# How can I create an animation frame with netbeans?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I use netbeans,and I insert an image on the lable which is on the desktop pane ,I want to rotate that image in its place ,what should i do?
please help me.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Graphics2D and specifically [this][1] method which lets you redraw the image with an AffineTransform and that lets you 'rotate' the image.

[1]: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image, java.awt.geom.AffineTransform, java.awt.image.ImageObserver)

Comment: I think, Johannas problem is not creating rotated or updated images but displaying an animation. Here's her previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021347/why-it-doesnt-draw-an-animated-curve